# xcode: following tutorial but 'subViewOneController' undeclared error

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I'm new to programming for the iPhone and I'm trying this new tutorial here:
http://theappleblog.com/2009/04/15/iphone-dev-sessions-create-a-navigation-based-application/

When I build the project, under the:
`RootViewController.m`

I get a 'subViewOneController' undeclared error at the first line:

```
// allocate a set of views and add to our view array as a dictionary item

SubViewOneController *subViewOneController = [[SubViewOneController alloc] init];

subViewOneController.title = @"Subview One";
```

What does the error mean? and where should I look to make sure names are matching?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that a class called `SubViewOneController` exists, and that you're importing its header (`SubViewOneController.h`) in `RootViewController.m`